# Admob display interstitial before segue - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, admob, segue, interstitial

I have a button that segue's over to another view. When the user clicks this button, I want to display an interstitial ad (if one is loaded) and then once the user dismisses the interstitial ad, then perform the segue as usual. If there was no interstitial ad, then perform the segue as normal.

I have some code that will display an interstitial, but when the user dismisses it, it takes them back to the previous view controller. They have to click the button again to be taken to the next view controller. Any tips?

```
// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(interstitial.isReady) {
            interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm trying to do something just about exactly similar to your question, but can't find any solutions. I just can't seem to fire the interstitial first, and THEN segue.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing. Once they watch the ad, I want it to proceed with the regular segue. So I added an alert with a callback. The only difference was mine was a UITableViewCell tap. In your case just do something like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton)
{
    self.presentViewController(interstitialAdAlert(
        { adWatched in
                if adWatched
                {
                    // perform segue here
                }
        }),
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}
```

Where `adWatched` is the callback parameter and `interstitialAdAlert(watchAdCallback: (adWatched: Bool)` is function that presents the alert as seen below:

```
func interstitialAdAlert(watchAdCallback: (adWatched: Bool) -> ()) -> UIAlertController
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Watch Ad?", message: "Your message here.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let watchAdAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Watch Ad", style: .Default)
        { (_) in
            self.interstitial.isReady ? self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self) : DDLogSwift.debug("The interstitial ad couldn't be loaded.")
            watchAdCallback(adWatched: true)
        }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel)
    { (_) in
            watchAdCallback(adChosen: false)
    }

    alert.addAction(watchAdAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    return alert
}
```

Hope this helps. Works like a charm for me with my tableview!
Oh, also make sure you create and load the interstitial ad in `viewWillAppear`.